# find whether the current user is a member of a specific audience?

Tags: audience-targeting, audiences

I am trying to find whether the current user is a member of a specific audience and used the below code however it returns "false" though the user belongs to the "testing" audience.

Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager.IsCurrentUserInAudienceOf("Testing",false)

what would be the issue?

**Update:**

**AIM:**
We would like to redirect the user based on the audience group.

**Eg.,**
If Userx is a member of the audience "Testing", he will be redirected to "newWeb" otherwise to "oldWeb".

**Implementation:**
DelegationControl loads a user control, validation & redirection is taken place on the user control.

**Update-2:**

Tried the below code however getting the "Access denied" error message while trying to get the audience - "Audience audience = audienceManager.GetAudience("Testing");", have verified and found that the app., pool has full control on the user profile application.

```
        else {  
                SPUser currentUser = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context).CurrentUser;  
                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate  
                        {  
                    //HttpContext httpCtxt = HttpContext.Current;  
                    //HttpContext.Current = null;  
                    Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager audienceManager = new 
Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager(SPServiceContext.Current);  
                    **Audience audience = audienceManager.GetAudience("Testing");**  
                    //HttpContext.Current = httpCtxt ;  
                    if ( audience.IsMember(currentUser.LoginName))  
                    {  
                        Page.Response.Redirect("http://www.redirectNew.com");  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        Page.Response.Redirect("http://www.redirectOld.com");  
                    }  
                });  
            }
```

Comment: If you still see unexpected results, look for an exception right about the same time it returns false. I realize SharePoint returns false when there is an unexpected error encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AudienceLoader objAudLoader = AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
AudienceManager.IsCurrentUserInAudienceOf(objAudLoader, audience, false)
```

The AudienceLoader belongs to Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience namespace and documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audiencemanager.iscurrentuserinaudienceof.aspx

**UPDATE**

If you still see unexpected results, look for an exception right about the same time it returns false. I realize SharePoint returns false when there is an unexpected error encountered.

Comment: Tried with the below code however it does not work as expected...returns "false" in all the cases...
Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.AudienceLoader objAudienceLoader = Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
if ( Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceManager.IsCurrentUserInAudienceOf(objAudienceLoader, "Testing", false)) {
 Page.Response.Redirect("http://redirectWebNew/person.aspx");
}
else {
 Page.Response.Redirect("http://redirectWebOld/person.aspx");
}

Comment: Testing is the name of the audience created in the User profile application in SharePoint 2010.....and the user is a member of the audience "Testing".

Comment: Have you resolved it yet? See my updated answer.

Comment: You have to pass the Id of the "Testing" audience. If you test "Testing" as audience, you'll never get true result.

Comment: yes, it works with the id. I want this part of the code should be executed before processing any other code. Now, the is inserted using a delegate control with the sequence number of 96. Is there anything can be done so that it will fire up first?

Answer (score 3):

## Step 1

The [AudienceLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.webcontrols.audienceloader.aspx) class is just a cache of the user's audience information and so it can sometimes give some misleading results. Try using the [Audience.IsMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audience.ismember.aspx) function instead:

```
Audience audience = audienceManager.GetAudience("Testing");
SPUser currentUser = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context).CurrentUser;

if (audience.IsMember(currentUser.LoginName))
{
    // Redirect user to newWeb
}
else
{
    // Redirect to oldWeb
}
```

Here are some other supporting cases:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ea67d79c-3ff4-4212-b627-dd6045cd0402

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/71b41b3c-9117-49f8-95a4-583be687505c/

## Step 2

Since changes made to audiences and audience rules are not reflected in the audience membership until it has been compiled, you will need to recompile your audiences in Central Administration before programatically performing the checks above. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263278.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try AudienceManager.IsMemberofAudience

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550183.aspx